# Force Media Update?

Tags: music-player, media-player, files

Sometimes I download songs from various sources, and they aren't put in the requisite media folder on external storage. The media scanner can still find them, but the only way I have found to do this is by moving the file around with a file manager, or mounting and unmounting as USB storage. This forces the phone to rescan for media files.

Does anyone know of a way to give Android a hint that it needs to rescan for media from within Android itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most custom ROMs include this functionality as part of the Power Widget.  For stock firmware you have to resort to 3rd-party apps such as [ScanMedia](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.humanrobot.scanmedia) or [SDRescan](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.bero.sdrescan), for example.

Comment: Another app I used to solve the same problem: MediaScanner.

Comment: Meridian Media Player has an option to rescan media in its toolkit section.

Comment: I wish there was a native way to do this, but thanks for the info everyone!

Comment: Both of these apps crash when I try to run them.   `java.lang.SecurityException ... not allowed to send broadcast ... MEDIA_MOUNTED`

Answer (score -1):

This is a very good question and I see it is already answered. I wrote a small application to solve this problem specifically for Kit Kit(Android 4.4+). My application works on all phones.

Here:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=burrows.apps.sdcard

This works on the Nexus 5!

Please let me know if this helps you!

Regards,