# Galaxy S2 does not see MP3 files in any player

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, mp3

I transferred several MP3 files to the Samsung Galaxy S2. But, the player does not see the MP3 files, only the DCT files. I installed several different players, and had the same result.

How do I fix the problem?

Comment: How did you transfer the files? Has the *Media Scanner* been running afterwards? See e.g.: [Force Media Update?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8526/16575)

Comment: also try to reset/reboot your phone. Sometimes, android does not properly mount the sdcard when it is unmounted from the computer. It will also run `media scanner` on startup.