# How to fix "Selected playlist is empty" in Android 4.1.2?

Tags: applications, 4.1-jelly-bean, music, music-player, zte

I have an old phone that I use as a dedicated MP3 player after my actual MP3 player died. It's a ZTE phone running Android 4.1.2 with an SD card that has all my music on it. I use the default music player on the phone. I've been having an odd problem recently where adding new music to the device causes the music player to be partially unable to play music. I'll move a song over and then when I start the music player and it loads to my song list clicking any of the listed songs merely gives me the message "selected playlist is empty". I can still play any of the songs if I switch over to any of the other tabs (organization methods?) like "Artist" or "Album" but not from the "Songs" tab. If I go back and remove the song that I moved over I can play music from the Songs tab again like normal.

This is getting very annoying because I can't put more music on the device I listen to music on. How do I fix it, without installing any new apps?

Comment: Android uses internally a database of media files. If you move a file in the file-system then the database entry is defect until it is updated. There are ways to force such an update manually: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8526/force-media-update

Comment: @Robert that doesn't really help. The check mark solution is just "get another app" and I can't get apps on this device. Besides, it's not the same problem as that question anyway. All my music is in the correct folder. The files show up, but I can't play anything at all from the tab in the music player that lists all my songs unless i go back and delete the newly added song. I can play things from the other tabs regardless, just not from the "Songs" tab.

Comment: Have you tried to use a different music player? May be the one you use has a bug which causes this behavior?

Comment: @Robert If you're asking if I've tried other devices, yes. I had everything on my original mp3 player before it broke. If you're asking about the app it's literally just the default one that came on the device, as i mentioned above. I've used it for years. No, I haven't tried another one because, as i also just mentioned, i can't get apps on this device.

Comment: I was talking about the app. Apps are software and thus can have bugs. Therefore I recommend to you to try a different music player app to see if it works or not with the problematic folder. If it works it is the app, if not it is some software component of the device.

Comment: @Robert I've said this twice already: I can't get more apps on this device.

Comment: If you can't install apps on an Android phone something is wrong with the phone. Then you should perform a factory reset are start over new.

Comment: @Robert there's nothing _wrong_ with the phone. It's just _really old_ for a phone. Can't use the app store anymore. No service, data, or signal. No updating. That's why it's my dedicated MP3 player. The only other thing it can do is act as a halfway decent paperweight.

Comment: Play Store is not the only way to install apps. The Izzy's F-Droid archive contains multiple Music player apps that work for Android 4.1. E.g. [Simple Music Player](https://apt.izzysoft.de/fdroid/index/apk/com.simplemobiletools.musicplayer?repo=archive) [Version 4.3.1](https://f-droid.org/archive/com.simplemobiletools.musicplayer_49.apk) is the last for Android 4.1. And there or other music player, too.

Comment: @Robert you're not helping at all and this website is displaying a complaint about how many comments we've made. So, please offer actual help or direct me to somebody that will.

Comment: Sorry that I am trying to help you. If you don't like may comments ignore them. Unfortunately nobody else has participated so in my opinion my comments are better than nothing. On your original problem I can't help you as I don't know your device nor the used music player app.